# Sending emails using sendmail in freebsd

Tags: freebsd, sendmail

I am trying to send a test email from command line (for debugging purpose).

I cannot make the sendmail to send the email. The Ctrl+d does not work on my ssh console and I could not find a solution by search.

[image: ma]

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but from my own experience, I'd recommend `ssmtp` over `sendmail`, as you'll find it's more efficient to use, especially if intending to use this in a script _(`ssmtp` uses `sendmail`)_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used the `-t` and `-i` options on the [sendmail(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sendmail&sektion=8) command line. If you drop the `-i` option, the email body will be terminated with the `.`.

For example:

```
sendmail -t root@example.com
From: me@example.com
Subject: Test
Test email
.
```

---

Alternatively, put the message into a separate file.

For example:

```
sendmail -t -i root@example.com < test.txt
```